# Python asyncio threaded listen for keypress 'r' or 'u' while allowing main program to run

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio

I am currently trying to build a threaded method of allowing a user to press the 'r' key at anytime to reload their config.ini file without restarting the app.

```
async def echo():
stdin, stdout = await aioconsole.get_standard_streams()
async for line in stdin:
    if (line == "r"):
        loadConfig()
    stdout.write(line)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(echo())
```

Not only does it not work, it does not allow the rest of the app to function as normal.

Wondering how to make a keypress listener operate background to the main app.

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: `run_until_complete` is a blocking function. Instead of passing `echo` to it, you should use something like `gather` to run both `echo` and whatever else you need to run.

Comment: Also, if you're building a "threaded" method, you don't need asyncio in the first palce, you can instantiate and start a `threading.Thread` that reads stdin (with ordinary blocking code) in the background. Also note that the user will need to press enter and that the line read will be `"r\n"`, not just `"r"`.